# OpenGL program compiles with C but not with C++

Tags: opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I'm learning OpenGL and am using SDL2. The problem I'm facing is that the code I write doesn't compile in C++ but the same code seems to compile fine in C. I have created a small excerpt of the program [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13730427/testgl.c).

When I compile this code using gcc it compiles and runs fine

```
$ gcc -o testgl testgl.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2 gl`
$ ./test 
OpenGL version : 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.58
```

But when I compile the same code using g++

```
$ g++ -o testgl testgl.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2 gl`
test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c:14:27: error: ‘glGenVertexArrays’ was not declared in this scope
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
                           ^
test.c:15:23: error: ‘glBindVertexArray’ was not declared in this scope
  glBindVertexArray(vao);
                       ^
```

While this isn't exactly an issue per say as I can simply use C instead of C++, but I want to know why such a thing happens and whether there is a way to fix this?

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04, GCC 4.8, SDL 2

Comment: gcc is not a C compiler. it is a multi-language compilation utility which will call g++ for .cpp extensions. So in your case, I guess the issue might be a header problem? gcc might be calling g++ with different flags than yours

Comment: I'm wrong in my previous comment. Even if gcc calls g++ for both c and c++ files, for a .c file gcc will call g++ with a C flag, while your command line for g++ will compile against a C++ standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that this is because C does not require function prototypes, whereas C++ does.

Compiling in C, you are eventually linking to the definitions in libGL and that works.  You don't technically need the headers for those functions.  Compiling in C++, you are missing the headers which provide the function prototypes.  You can use GLEW for that or you can load GL functions yourself with OS-specific APIs (e.g. wgl, glx).